# Why does float.Parse("123,45") not throw an exception

Tags: c#, string, parsing, floating-point

... but returns 12345?

The doc for [Single.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Single_Parse_System_String_) says:

> **Exceptions**
>
> ...
>
> FormatException
>
> `s` does not represent a numeric value.
>
> ...

For my understanding "123,45" doesn't represent a proper numeric value (in countries that use comma as thousands separator).

The system's CultureInfo has:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator == "."
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator == ","
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes == [3]
```

Apparently the comma is simply ignored and this leads to even more irritating results: "123,45.67" or "1,23,45.67"–which look utterly wrong–become 12345.67.

#### Supplementary question

I don't get what this sentence in the doc is supposed to mean and whether this is relevant for this case:

> If a separator is encountered in the `s` parameter during a parse operation, and the applicable currency or number decimal and group separators are the same, the parse operation assumes that the separator is a decimal separator rather than a group separator.

Comment: I suspect this is because `NumberGroupSeparator` separates number groups, not “thousands” as [most of the world separates large numbers into groups other than thousands](http://www.statisticalconsultants.co.nz/blog/how-the-world-separates-its-digits.html).

Comment: @DourHighArch Thanks for the hint, but apparently .NET Fiddle's server isn't configured for Japan, China or India. ;) See the update to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the default and US culture, the comma (`,`) is legal as a separator between groups. Think of larger numbers like this:

```
987,654,321
```

That it's in the wrong place for a group doesn't really matter; the parser isn't that smart. It just ignores the separator.

For the supplemental question, some cultures use commas as the decimal separator, rather than a group separator. This part of the documentation clarifies what will happen if the group separator and decimal separator are somehow set to the same character.

Comment: I know that the comma is used like that. That's not the reason for my question. The only answer really seems to be: "the parser isn't that smart". I also know the "comma as decimal separator". I live in such a country. :) That's why I showed up here with this question since I have to handle number inputs that could be either of them. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you're worried about distinguishing types of inputs, I suggest *and I can't believe I'm writing this) a regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

As Joel said, "the parser isn't that smart". The source code is available, so here's the proof.

The code for [`Single.Parse`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/single.cs,211) ends up calling [`Number.ParseNumber`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,741).

Interestingly, `Number.ParseNumber` *is* given a `NumberFormatInfo` object, which does have a [`NumberGroupSizes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupsizes) property, which defines "the number of digits in each group to the left of the decimal".

However, you'll notice that on line [851](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,851), where it checks for the group separator, it doesn't bother to reference the `NumberGroupSizes` property to check if the group separator is in an expected position. In fact `Number.ParseNumber` *never* uses the `NumberGroupSizes` property.

`NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSizes` is only ever used when converting a number to a string.